# cmake kms-elements gstreamer-sctp-1.5

Tags: cmake, gstreamer, kurento

## First

i get the source of kms-element from https://github.com/Kurento/kms-elements

```
git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kms-elements.git
```

## Then

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

## Result

**package 'gstreamer-sctp-1.5' not found**

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
If KurentoHelpers is not found, then it is necessary to install
          kms-cmake-utils package from the kurento repository
-- Found KurentoHelpers: 1.3.3~1.g24e0763 (found version "1.3.3~1.g24e0763") 
-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "1.9.1") 
If CodeGenerator is not found, then it is necessary to install
          kms-core package from the kurento repository
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.26") 
-- Found /usr/bin/kurento-module-creator
-- Found /usr/bin/kurento-module-creator
-- Found KurentoModuleCreator: 4.0.8-SNAPSHOT (found version "4.0.8-SNAPSHOT") 
-- Resolving KurentoModuleCreator version ^4.0.0 with 4.0.8-SNAPSHOT
-- Version got from git is 6.6.2~2.g7595ce1
-- Boost version: 1.55.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   unit_test_framework
-- Found Boost COMPONENTS unit_test_framework
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-1.5'
--   found gstreamer-1.5, version 1.8.1.1
-- Resolving gstreamer-1.5 version ^1.5.0 with 1.8.1.1
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.5'
--   found gstreamer-base-1.5, version 1.8.1.1
-- Resolving gstreamer-base-1.5 version ^1.5.0 with 1.8.1.1
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-video-1.5'
--   found gstreamer-video-1.5, version 1.8.1.1
-- Resolving gstreamer-video-1.5 version ^1.5.0 with 1.8.1.1
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.5'
--   found gstreamer-app-1.5, version 1.8.1.1
-- Resolving gstreamer-app-1.5 version ^1.5.0 with 1.8.1.1
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-check-1.5'
--   found gstreamer-check-1.5, version 1.8.1.1
-- Resolving gstreamer-check-1.5 version ^1.5.0 with 1.8.1.1
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-sdp-1.5'
--   found gstreamer-sdp-1.5, version 1.8.1.1
-- Resolving gstreamer-sdp-1.5 version ^1.5.0 with 1.8.1.1
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-rtp-1.5'
--   found gstreamer-rtp-1.5, version 1.8.1.1
-- Resolving gstreamer-rtp-1.5 version ^1.5.0 with 1.8.1.1
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.5'
--   found gstreamer-pbutils-1.5, version 1.8.1.1
-- Resolving gstreamer-pbutils-1.5 version ^1.5.0 with 1.8.1.1
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-sctp-1.5'
--   package 'gstreamer-sctp-1.5' not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/GenericFind.cmake:131 (message):
  Library gstreamer-sctp-1.5 not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:40 (generic_find)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

## Try

the gstreamer i had installed. 
 this is the libs for gstreamer i hava tried.

```
libgst7                            libgstreamer1.5-dev                libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.5-dev
libgstbuzztard0                    libgstreamer-interfaces-perl       libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0
libgstbuzztard-dev                 libgstreamermm-0.10-2              libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev
libgst-dev                         libgstreamermm-0.10-dbg            libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0
libgstreamer0.10-0                 libgstreamermm-0.10-dev            libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
libgstreamer0.10-0-dbg             libgstreamermm-0.10-doc            libgstreamer-plugins-base1.5-0
libgstreamer0.10-cil-dev           libgstreamer-ocaml                 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.5-dev
libgstreamer0.10-dev               libgstreamer-ocaml-dev             libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0
libgstreamer0.9-cil                libgstreamer-perl                  libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-dev
libgstreamer1.0-0                  libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-0     libgstreamer-vaapi1.0-0
libgstreamer1.0-0-dbg              libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-dev   libgstreamer-vaapi1.0-dev
libgstreamer1.0-dev                libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0      libgstrtspserver-0.10-0
libgstreamer1.5-0                  libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev    libgstrtspserver-0.10-dev
libgstreamer1.5-0-dbg              libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.5-0
```

## Why

how can i go on?

Comment: Maybe you also need to install the headers?

Comment: Thanks. oh? What headers? How to install the special headers?

Comment: Usually they are called -dev, or -devel.

Comment: i've tried , but are the same . Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/Kurento/usrsctp.git
./bootstrap
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

and you may need to install gtk-doc-tools

```
sudo apt-get install gtk-doc-tools
```